# Output text into a textbox C++

Tags: c++, string, textbox, output, edit

I've been googling for a while and I found nothing working for me so I'm here asking you folks this question.

I've already tried with SendMessage, SetWindowText and much more.

What I am trying to do is output a text in a textbox ( TEXT("edit") ... ).
The messages I have to display are: "You win", "You lose" or "Draw".

What do you suggest me to do?

(I'm using DEV C++)

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Posting a piece of code representing what you have tried so far would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right, that's what I've done so far:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yzA0jPX5

Comment: Don't use pastebin. Instead, post any relevant code here so that questions are complete and don't rely on external sources.

Comment: Well, how do you inseret the code? I'm getting an error (Too many characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet:

```
HWND hwndbutton[2];
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
           case WM_CREATE:
hwndbutton[0] = CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"),TEXT(""), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD |
                             WS_BORDER,10,10,50,30, hwnd, (HMENU)11,0,0);
```

looks like it is inside a window procedure - first problem is that the value in hwndbutton[0] will be lost (it's on the stack) when the procedure is called again. You could, for example, make it static:

```
static HWND hwndbutton[2];
```

Tracing through your debugger should show you this.